# error in imagic librarie - php

Tags: php, imagick

i am trying to use the class Imagick in the vertigo serv

i have this form

```
<form action="thumb.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>
      <label for="file">Select a file:</label> 
      <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"> <br />
      <button>Upload File</button>
   <p>
</form>
```

and this php

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$imagePath = $_FILES["userfile"];

$thumbnailWidth = 100;
$thumbnailHeight = 100;

$srgbPath = 'thumb/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc';

$image = new Imagick($imagePath);

$width = $image->getImageWidth();
$height = $image->getImageHeight();

$srgb = file_get_contents($srgbPath);
$image->profileImage('icc', $srgb);

$image->stripImage();

$image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);

$fitWidth = ($thumbnailWidth / $width) < ($thumbnailHeight / $height);

$image->thumbnailImage(
$fitWidth ? $thumbnailWidth : 0,
$fitWidth ? 0 : $thumbnailHeight
);

$imagePathParts = pathinfo($imagePath);
$thumbnailPath = "thumb/miniaturas/".
$imagePathParts['filename'].'_'.
$thumbnailWidth.'x'.$thumbnailHeight.'.jpg';

$image->setImageCompressionQuality(90);

$image->writeImage($thumbnailPath);
echo $image;
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();

?>
```

and i receive this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\main_image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2587' in C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\thumb.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\thumb.php(12): Imagick->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\thumb.php on line 12

i am trying to open a image that is located in the desktop but the error seems to search in the localhost paste:

**`C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login\main_image.jpg':**

any idea?

if i change this

```
$imagePath = $_FILES["userfile"];
```

to this

```
$imagePath = 'thumb/main.jpg';
```

all works fine

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A core problem you have is the path for the uploaded file. `$_FILES["userfile"];` doesn't give you the file path, it gives you an array of file details (see http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp for more info).

Your image will be copied into the PHP temporary directory, and its location can be found using `$imagePath = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];`.

PHP will look within the folder that your script is running from by default, which will be why its looking in `C:\Users\fel\VertrigoServ\www\login`. This means you'll either need your "thumbs" directory (where you save the thumbnail) in that folder, or to give the path to the correct location in full.

The rest of the code looks alright on first glance :)

Comment: man, another question related to this script. actually the name is php1EEA_100x100 or php65BA_100x100. This names will be always  different? so, i can store it in the database without the risk of override?

Comment: In reality, the names are likely to be different, although I don't think there's anything to force them to be unique. One thing to bear in mind - I'm not sure if this is relevant or not - is that the image that's uploaded will get thrown away by PHP when its done with it, because it's in the temp directory. If you're going to need the original image at any later point, you'll need to do use `move_uploaded_file()` to put it somewhere permanent. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
$imagePath = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];
```

[w3Schools ref](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp)

the main `$_FILES["userfile"]` is an array that hold all the file information.